# Switch to date picker and click on next month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

[image]

```html
<button class="mat-calendar-next-button mat-icon-button" mat-icon-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-disabled="false" aria-label="Next month"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

```html
<mat-calendar class="mat-calendar ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeInCalendar" cdktrapfocus="" ng-reflect-enabled="" ng-reflect-start-view="month" id="mat-datepicker-0" style="opacity: 1;"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-portal": "[object Object]"
}--><mat-calendar-header class="ng-star-inserted" style=""><div class="mat-calendar-header"><div class="mat-calendar-controls"><button cdkarialive="polite" class="mat-calendar-period-button mat-button" mat-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-politeness="polite" aria-label="Choose month and year"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">FEB 2019<div class="mat-calendar-arrow"></div></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button><div class="mat-calendar-spacer"></div><button class="mat-calendar-previous-button mat-icon-button" mat-icon-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-disabled="false" aria-label="Previous month"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button><button class="mat-calendar-next-button mat-icon-button" mat-icon-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-disabled="false" aria-label="Next month"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button></div></div></mat-calendar-header><div cdkmonitorsubtreefocus="" class="mat-calendar-content" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-ng-switch="month"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "month"
}--><mat-month-view ng-reflect-active-date="Sun Feb 10 2019 16:39:30 GMT+0" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""><table class="mat-calendar-table"><thead class="mat-calendar-table-header"><tr><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><th aria-label="Sunday" class="ng-star-inserted">Su</th><th aria-label="Monday" class="ng-star-inserted">Mo</th><th aria-label="Tuesday" class="ng-star-inserted">Tu</th><th aria-label="Wednesday" class="ng-star-inserted">We</th><th aria-label="Thursday" class="ng-star-inserted">Th</th><th aria-label="Friday" class="ng-star-inserted">Fr</th><th aria-label="Saturday" class="ng-star-inserted">Sa</th></tr><tr><th aria-hidden="true" class="mat-calendar-table-header-divider" colspan="7"></th></tr></thead><tbody aria-readonly="true" class="mat-calendar-body" mat-calendar-body="" role="grid" ng-reflect-label="FEB" ng-reflect-rows="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-today-value="10" ng-reflect-label-min-required-cells="3" ng-reflect-active-cell="9"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><tr role="row" class="ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "5"
}--><td aria-hidden="true" class="mat-calendar-body-label ng-star-inserted" colspan="5" style="padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;">FEB</td><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 1, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">1</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 2, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">2</div></td></tr><tr role="row" class="ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 3, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">3</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 4, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">4</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 5, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">5</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 6, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">6</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 7, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">7</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 8, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">8</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 9, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">9</div></td></tr><tr role="row" class="ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell mat-calendar-body-active ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" aria-label="February 10, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content mat-calendar-body-today">10</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 11, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">11</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 12, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">12</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 13, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">13</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 14, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">14</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 15, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">15</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 16, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">16</div></td></tr><tr role="row" class="ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 17, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">17</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 18, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">18</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 19, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">19</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 20, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">20</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 21, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">21</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 22, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">22</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 23, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">23</div></td></tr><tr role="row" class="ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 24, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">24</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 25, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">25</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 26, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">26</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 27, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">27</div></td><td class="mat-calendar-body-cell ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" aria-label="February 28, 2019" aria-selected="false" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content">28</div></td></tr></tbody></table></mat-month-view><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "year"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "multi-year"
}--></div></mat-calendar>
```

I have a date picker with the elements mentioned in the code snippet. This date picker opens up on a dialog pop up . The dialog pop up is identified by element(by.css('.mat-dialog-container'));

But, I am unable to click on 'Next Month' and pick a date from this calendar. Any help would be great!

Comment: What failure does message does your script return?

Comment: It says : Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        const calendar = element(by.tagName('mat-datepicker-toggle'));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(calendar), 50000);
        calendar.click();
        const next = element(by.className('mat-calendar-next-button'));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(next), 50000);
        next.click();
```

Comment: this gives me an error. Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Which version of angular you are using?

Comment: I'm currently on the following versions:    Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.5
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.5
@schematics/angular          0.8.5
@schematics/update           0.8.5
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2

Comment: Try this:  element(by.cssContainingText('mat-icon-button', 'Next month'));

Comment: Well, i still get the same error. Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Can you share the code which you have written for clicking on calendar and next button

Comment: This is the code i have written and tried executing:   element(by.css('[ng-reflect-name=end_date]')).click();
browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement();
element(by.cssContainingText('mat-icon-button', 'Next month')).click();

Comment: There is no need of browser.driver.switchTo(). I have updated the answer replace your code with that.

Comment: unknown error: Element<input _ngcontent-c39=""class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"matinput=""name="end_date"placeholder="Close Date" ng-reflect-mat-datepicker="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="end_date"ng-reflect-model=""ng-reflect-placeholder="Close Date"aria-haspopup="true"id="mat-input-2"aria-invalid="false"aria-required="false"aria-owns="mat-datepicker-0"> is not clickable at point (496, 507)

Comment: .Other element would receive the click:<div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop mat-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>

Comment: Hi, Used your updated answer and the above 2 comments have the error i got.

Comment: Are you getting this error after clicking on calendar?

Comment: Not after clicking on calendar. It is after the calendar loads, it is trying to search and click on the next icon

Comment: You have any suggestions?

Comment: In my case I am using the above updated code for clicking on calendar and next button. The date picker used from angular material. You can try that if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Understand the webtable concept first .I would prefer you first go through
mukesh otwani's dynamic calender handle tutorial then apply the same logic here
2.Click on the calender icon 
3.Click on navigation link
4.Click on date
Avoid using element .all to loop through and select the date you'll get stale element reference error
5.Use filter concept from protractors official website to click on an element than loop through each and very element and click
6.Make sure you pass the date as an argument than hard coding the date . 
Try this if not i'll share you code to overcome this .

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestions. But, I am looking at a solution in protractor with Javascript. Mukesh Otwani's tutorial is brilliant for selenium. Need a solution for this in Protractor.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution. Any leads would help.